Columns With No Statistics warning quering indexed view WITH (NOEXPAND)
I am querying the indexed view with aggregate function WITH(NOEXPAND) hint.
SELECT MIN(Column) FROM dbo.vwi_indexed_view WITH(NOEXPAND);

I am getting Columns With No Statistics warning inside the actual execution plan.

I have Auto Update Statistics set to True on database.
This should not be the case If I interpret this article correctly: https://sqlperformance.com/2014/01/sql-plan/indexed-views-and-statistics
Should it be the aggregate function to blame, for what reason?
While I create the column statistics manually, the warning disappears.
SQL Server 2019, Developer edition

Perhaps you disabled autosts for this particular table?

I am not aware of any auto-stats option for a particular table.  As for index statistics, there is NO no-recompute set. And I can see auto-created statistics (_WA_Sys...) for the indexed view.
